# Flutter initState() returns '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter returns error `'_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not true.` when trying to call `initState()`

Here is my `initState()` function. I have ensured it isn't inside the `build()` function as mentioned by another similar question on this site.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dataRead = false;

    todayTask.clear();
    tomorrowTask.clear();
    upcomingTask.clear();

    tasks().then((data) {
      setState(() {

        for (int i =0; i< data.length; i++){
          if (taskDay(DateTime.parse(data[i].datetime)) == 0) todayTask.add(data[i]);
          else if (taskDay(DateTime.parse(data[i].datetime)) == 1) tomorrowTask.add(data[i]);
          else upcomingTask.add(data[i]);
        }

        dataRead = true;

      });
    });

    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }
```

The error does not appear the first time `initState()` is run. It only appears when I explicitly call it.

Result of flutter run --verbose

```
[ +166 ms] E/flutter (30434): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1113 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState ==
_StateLifecycle.created': is not true.
[   +2 ms] E/flutter (30434): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:39)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #2      State.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1113:12)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #3      _TodoBodyState.initState (package:dyry/todobody.dart:70:11)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #4      _TodoBodyState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dyry/todobody.dart:162:75)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #5      _AddTodoState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:dyry/addtodo.dart:321:36)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #6      _AddTodoState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:dyry/addtodo.dart)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:953:19)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1059:38)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:522:11)
[        ] E/flutter (30434): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:254:7)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #13     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
[   +2 ms] E/flutter (30434): #15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:281:10)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (30434): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:190:5)
[   +2 ms] E/flutter (30434):
[  +92 ms] D/InputMethodManager(30434): HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 30434
```

Comment: Can you modify your question with the result of `flutter run --verbose`?

Comment: @Akif Edited my question with the result

Comment: Try running the code in a separate function which is marked async. It helped me fix it when I faced the problem. Then use await instead of .then. Seems weird but may fix the problem

Comment: @SiddharthAgarwal Thanks a Lot! I made another function. And bow I am just calling that function instead of initState()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than FutureDelayed, you should make another function and call that function in initState.
I had the same problem, I fixed it with just extract the function.
There's my code:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    getInitData();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getInitData() async {
    await Provider.of<PassCardList>(context, listen: false).getCard();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the setState is used before the widget is created. I would put a delay for the setState.

```
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        dataRead = false;
    
        todayTask.clear();
        tomorrowTask.clear();
        upcomingTask.clear();

       Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
    
        tasks().then((data) {
          setState(() {
    
            for (int i =0; i< data.length; i++){
              if (taskDay(DateTime.parse(data[i].datetime)) == 0) todayTask.add(data[i]);
              else if (taskDay(DateTime.parse(data[i].datetime)) == 1) tomorrowTask.add(data[i]);
              else upcomingTask.add(data[i]);
            }
    
            dataRead = true;
    
          });
        });
});
    
        _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
      }
```

Comment: The error persists despite adding a delay of 2 seconds.

Comment: Did you try to remove the setState to see if the error appears when you remove it?